# Webresource.axd in Internet Explorer

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer, webresource.axd

I am using ASP.NET web forms -It has a dropdown list:

```
    <asp:DropDownList ID="dldaypre" runat="server"> 

                <asp:ListItem Value="-1" Text="What day do you prefer to meet?*"></asp:ListItem>

              <asp:ListItem Value="Monday" Text="Monday"></asp:ListItem>
                 <asp:ListItem Value="Tuesday" Text="Tuesday"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Value="Wednesday" Text="Wednesday"></asp:ListItem>
                       <asp:ListItem Value="Thursday" Text="Thursday"></asp:ListItem>
                          <asp:ListItem Value="Friday" Text="Friday"></asp:ListItem>
                          <asp:ListItem Value="Saturday" Text="Saturday"></asp:ListItem>
                             <asp:ListItem Value="Sunday" Text="Sunday"></asp:ListItem>                


              </asp:DropDownList>

              <asp:RequiredFieldValidator InitialValue="-1" ID="Req_ID" Display="Dynamic" 
runat="server" ControlToValidate="dldaypre"
Text="Selection required" ErrorMessage="Selection required"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

When I try to run this in Internet Explorer, and select the option in the dropdown list, following error appears in webresource.axd:

Unable to get value of the property 'length': object is null or undefined

Any workaround for this?

Comment: The problem doesn't seem to be in your aspx (shown above).  Can you post the code (code-behind) for this page.  That is where the error probably is.